# change number of elements color

Tags: jquery

I have table in this format:

```
<tr>
  <td><span></span></td>
  <td><span></span></td>
  <td><span></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><span></span></td>
  <td><span></span></td>
  <td><span></span></td>
</tr>
```

when click on some SPAN i would like that **all** the spans inside the specific TR will get grey color.

how can I do that?

```
element.parent("tr").children("span").attr('style', 'color: #838282 !important');
```

Comment: `element.closest("tr").find('span')`? - `span`s are not children of `tr`, they are descendants

Comment: As a sidenote, `!important` doesn't work in javascript, and is pointless.

Comment: What do you mean when you wrote  in specific TR? Does you elements has specific classes or you`d like to change color for TR`s that are not direct parents of this span... can you explain?

Comment: weird no-one recommended `css class` approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span` is not direct child so you need to use **[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find)** and `tr` is parent of `td` not parent of `span` so use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest)**. For applying style use **[`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css)**, also there is no need of `!important` in **[`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css)**.

```
$('tr span').click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").find("span").css('color', '#838282');
});
```

Comment: @Diptox `parents` will select all the parent elements, if the table is nested, the result will be unexpected

Comment: @Tushar - funnily enough, it probably works for the OP when setting the entire `style` attribute, but it wouldn't work in these answers when using `css()`.

Comment: @Tushar you can tr:eq(0)

Answer (score 1):

- Jquery `parents(selector)` get the match selector in ancestors
- Jquery `find(selector)` get the match children in children tree

Run the code snippet to see result

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").find("span").attr('style', 'color: #838282');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>A</span>
    </td>
    <td><span>B</span>
    </td>
    <td><span>C</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>D</span>
    </td>
    <td><span>E</span>
    </td>
    <td><span>F</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this JavaScript code:

```
$('tr span').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('span').css('color', '#838282');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span").on("click",function()
{
    $(this).parents("tr").find("span").css('color', '#838282');
});
```

Comment: `parents` will select all the parent elements, if the table is nested, the result will be unexpected

Comment: Why, when the `closest` does the same thing

Comment: @Tushar you can see it here https://api.jquery.com/closest#entry-longdesc
they are similar but closest is a little bit faster

Comment: This doesn't explain why the code works or what it does. Needs explanation.

Comment: This is what does the code . when u click on a span it will search for parent that is a tr "in your case you have only one table so this code will work perfectly for u" then it will select all span children of that tr then change their color :D